# SBT Basic Auth Problems

Tags: sbt, bamboo

I'm setting up SBT on our buildserver (bamboo) for multiple buildagents. For this I created for each agent a separate directory which contains the agent specific config and the .ivy home to make sure agent isolation is fullfilled.
The build itself is call like this:

```
/sbt-launcher-packaging-0.13.13/bin/sbt -java-home /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_79 -Dsbt.override.build.repos=true -Dsbt.repository.config=/data/bamboo/localbuildagents/${bamboo.agentId}/sbt/sbt.conf -Dsbt.ivy.home=/data/bamboo/localbuildagents/${bamboo.agentId}/.ivy2 clean compile dist
```

The credentials (basic realm) are store under the user home which is starting the bamboo server (~/.sbt/.credentials and ~/.sbt/0.13/plugins/credentials.sbt)

Each sbt.conf contains the agent-specific repos e.g the agent specific local maven repo and urls for the remote artifactory.

```
[repositories]
  local-buildagent-mvn:  file:///data/bamboo/home/.m2/AGENT-xxxxxxxx/repository/
  ivy-release:   http://xxx/artifactory/ivy-release/,  [organization]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]
  mvn-release:   http://xxx/artifactory/libs-release/
  mvn-snapshot:  http://xxx/artifactory/libs-snapshot/  

[ivy]
  ivy-home:   file:///data/bamboo/localbuildagents/xxxxxxxx/.ivy2/
```

I'm encountering login problems while sbt is checking the remote artifactory repos (first http error 401 and then surprisingly 403). A curl with the same credentials and repo url is working as expected (first 401 and then 200).

I guess, that if -D switches are used for sbt startup, the credentials are not considered. I'm really stuck any advise warmly welcome...

Answer (score 0):

From your question I don't see if you specified where your credentials are defined. In case you didn't do it, you must add something like this to your build definition ([documentation](https://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Publishing.html#Credentials)):

```
// inline
credentials += Credentials("Some Nexus Repository Manager", "my.artifact.repo.net", "admin", "admin123")

// file 
credentials += Credentials(Path.userHome / ".ivy2" / ".credentials")
```

Comment: Credentials are stored under ~/.sbt/.credentials, this file is formatted in the "realm" layout. Under the path ~/.sbt/0.13/plugins/credentials.sbt which contains the 2nd content you mentioned (with adopted path of course).

Comment: But did you specify the path to the credentials file in your build.sbt? I don't think the .credentials file is found automatically...